British (BBC?) miniseries from mid-2000s (?) - man moves to rural village, falls in love with schoolteacher
I am trying to identify a BBC or PBS miniseries I saw many years ago. I believe it aired somewhere around the mid 2000s on PBS in the US, and I think it was two two-hour episodes, or thereabouts. My memory of it is very vague, but here is what I recall.
It takes place in a small rural village in I think Scotland or England. There are two main characters: a man who arrives in the village to start a new job, and a woman who is a schoolteacher there. They eventually fall in love. I think the man stays with a family there: a husband, wife, and children.
I remember one scene where a group of schoolchildren are being taken on a tour of a museum or library, when one of the students notices a steady drip of water from the ceiling, which leads to the entire building needing to be restored(?), or abandoned(?). 
I think there is a part where almost everyone in the town has to leave, and the only ones who stay are the man and maybe a few others. This gives it sort of an apocalyptic feel. I think there is something about the man having to fight corruption of a greedy corporation, or something like that. Also, almost everyone rides a bicycle to get around, but there are cars as well. The scenery is all rolling green hills and quaint stone buildings. I may be slightly misremembering some of these things.

Can you see if this is Monarch of the Glen ? There are a lot of similiarities...

No, it's not. That was a multi-season show. I am certain that what I am asking about was a short miniseries. But you're right that there are many similarities. Thank you for the guess!

Could you be thinking of 'Doc Martin'?  The show starred Martin Clunes as a surgeon who developed a fear of blood and so, moves to a small town to practice General Medicine.

No, it wasn't Doc Martin. This was definitely a short miniseries, not a multi-season show, but thanks for the guess!
